# Why doesn't "complement" work as a function?

Tags: elisp, common-lisp, lexical-scoping

I'm trying to implement the `complement` [function from Common Lisp](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_comple.htm) (CL) in Emacs Lisp, but I'm confused by why defining it as a function (as opposed to a macro) does not work.

The macro definition is straightforward:

```
(defmacro complement (function)
  `(lambda (&rest args)
     (not (apply ,function args))))
```

The function definition, however, does not work.

```
(defun complement (f)
  (lambda (&rest args)
    (not (apply f args))))
```

Something like `(complement #'zerop)` gives

```
(lambda (&rest args) (not (apply f args)))
```

Where the `f` is not replaced with the `zerop`.

Why is this? The equivalent function definition works fine in CL. Does it have something to do with scope?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this behavior is explained by differences in [Variable Scoping](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Variable-Scoping.html#Variable-Scoping) between Emacs Lisp and Common Lisp.

In Common Lisp (a lexically scoped lisp) a lambda returned by `complement` you defined is turned into a *closure*, i.e. it captures the lexical environment that existed when it was created.

Here's what I get from SBCL:

```
*
(defun my-complement (f)
  (lambda (&rest args)
    (not (apply f args))))

MY-COMPLEMENT
* (my-complement #'zerop)

#<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (&REST ARGS) :IN MY-COMPLEMENT) {1002CD5BEB}>
```

In Emacs Lisp (which uses dynamic binding) your `complement` returns the form "`(lambda (&rest args) (not (apply f args)))`", which does not "see" that `f` was bound to `#'zerop` because it cannot "capture" the environment it is created in. ([Closures](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Closures.html#Closures) can exist only in the context of lexical binding.)

You **can** enable lexical binding in Emacs Lisp by setting `lexical-binding` to `t`. This is a file-local variable, so you would usually put

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
```

near the top of the file to achieve this.

With this change the functional version of `complement` works in Emacs Lisp.

As for why this works as a macro in Emacs Lisp, a [macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Expansion.html#Expansion) generates the form *with* the value of `f` captured (you took care of it by using a backquote and a comma) and then the resulting form is evaluated, turning the form `(lambda (&rest args) ...)` into an anonymous function you can call.

Both steps are important: without the backquote you can't capture `f`, and without evaluation all you get is a funny-looking list `(lambda (&rest args) ...)` that you'd have to `eval` "by hand".

PS: I'm not a Lisp expert. Comments, corrections, and edits are always welcome.

Answer (score 9):

What @Constantine said about lexical and dynamic scoping is true, and it explains the difference from Common Lisp behavior.

However, there is something misleading in your question.  This really **has nothing to do with macros**.  Here is a definition using `defun` instead of `defmacro`. Note that you need a quote mark (`'`) before the use of `,function`: `',function`, because you want `'zerop` and not `zerop` (which would be evaluated as a variable).

```el
(defun complement (function)
  "Return a function that complements the effect of FUNCTION.
The resulting function applies FUNCTION to any number of args
and returns the Boolean complement of the result."
  `(lambda (&rest args)
     (not (apply ',function args))))

(funcall (complement #'zerop) 0)   ; Returns nil
(funcall (complement #'zerop) 3)   ; Returns t

(complement #'zerop) ; Returns (lambda (&rest args) (not (apply (quote zerop) args)))
```

When you use `',function` you are not leaving `function` as a free variable in the resulting function (lambda form).  Instead, because of the backquote surrounding the comma, the value of FUNCTION that is passed to function `complement` is **substituted** for `,function`, and then quoted.

So when `zerop` is passed as argument to `complement` it is substituted for `,function` and then quoted, producing `'zerop` within the resulting lambda form.  The backquote expression constructs a **list**:

```
(lambda (&rest args) (not (apply 'zerop args)))
```

When you use `complement` that list is evaluated to a function and used as such.

So the *difference* between this approach and the use of free variable `function` in the lexical binding case (that is, the use of a closure that couples (a) the lambda form that has free variable `function` with (b) an environment in which that variable is bound to `zerop`) is that:

1. In this approach there is *no* variable in the resulting form, and
2. The resulting form is a *list*, not a function.

Number 1 means that you cannot use the variable for anything when the lambda form is used as a function, because, *Hey! - it isn't there*.

And it means that unless you explicitly go to the trouble of byte-compiling the resulting form (which is a list, whose car is `lambda` etc.), evaluation is slower, because you are interpreting a list as a lambda form and that as a function - you do not have a (possibly byte-compiled) function directly.

When might you care whether you have a *variable* at the time the function is used? When you need to do something with that variable *as a variable*!  For example, you assign it another value than `function` at some point.  In most cases you do *not* need the variable as a variable - it is enough to have its *value* (in this case, `zerop`) when the function is used.

Comment: My understanding is that it's usually good practice to turn lexical binding on for Emacs Lisp (e.g. when writing packages) these days. If we stuck to dynamic binding, however, would you prefer the macro over the defun due to the resulting form being a list instead of a function in the latter case?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with turning lexical binding on. And there is nothing wrong with leaving it off (IMHO). If the lambda form is too costly when used then yes, you can use `defmacro` (or `defsubst`). Typically it is not, in my experience. Also, you cannot `funcall` or `apply` a macro, etc. There is nothing new here - the usual tradeoffs and other considerations apply.